# What am I? Not tricky

Tags: riddle

> What is the same for people surrounding me,
>
> But different for people far away from me,
>
> And if I move, it changes for me.

Comment: This would be a lot easier to read if you put all the parentheticals outside of the riddle, instead of trying to explain the riddle while you "tell" it..

Comment: Are those parentheses really required?? Or you can just do away with it..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> Time, or time zone

Explanation:

> The time zone is the same for a region, but if you leave the region (go far), it changes. Moreover, if you move to a different time zone, the time is different there.

Answer (score 3):

As simple as

> your location?

Because

> people around you are in the same location, but those far away are not.  If you move, your location changes.

Answer (score 2):

> Point of View?  (In a very real, physical, 30 character long sense)

Answer (score 2):

> Perspective

Because

> Those standing where you are share your perspective (angles relating to surrounding objects).
> People far away have a different perspective.
> When you move, your perspective changes.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking it is

> SUN which means DAY

Because if it is

> day and someone who is around you they can see SUN.

And

> Who is far away from you, like on the other side of the globe, it will be Night for them. so they cant see SUN.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE. Please [use >! in front of your answer for adding spoilers, click here](https://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/241/how-to-format-text-inside-spoilers). Also, please refrain from using SMS language :)